# Android OKHTTP StringEntity

Tags: android, http, okhttp, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using OKHTTP to send POST requests to Microsoft Text Analytics API, but can't figure out StringEntity's counterpart in OKHTTP's request body.

The HTTP Request I want to send is:

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages?numberOfLanguagesToDetect=1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
    {
      "documents": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "text": "example string"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The way I wrote right now is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/languages").newBuilder();
urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("numberOfLanguagesToDetect", "1");
String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

JSONObject text = new JSONObject();
text.put("id", "string");
text.put("text", "example string");
MediaType jsonMT = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody rBody = RequestBody.create(jsonMT, text.toString());
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                  .header("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", sub-key)
                  .url(url)
                  .post(rBody)
                  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
ResponseBody body = response.body();
```

However, this is incorrect. How can I format my request body so that it is  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "text": "example string"
    }
  ]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 JSONObject document = new JSONObject();
 document.put("id", "string");
 document.put("text", "example string");
 JSONArray documents = new JSONArray();
 documents.put(document);
 JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
 root.put("documents", documents);
```